# TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null does not stop appearing

Tags: javascript

I write this code about a budget calculator while watching the solution of my proffessor for this exercise, and while mine is almost the same is not running. Although I fill the tables, when I start updating my form elements using DOM i get the next errors:

in Google Chrome i get the error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null 
in Firefox:  TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null

When i open the page the body calls the function formInit().

```
var Accounts= new Array("blah", "blah1");

        var MoneySpent= new Array();
        var Rates= new Array();
        var bud=1000;
        var rem;
        var maxrate=100;
        var i;

        function initArrays(){
            for (i=0; i< 20; i++){
                if (Accounts[i]=null)
                    Accounts[i]='Account #'+i;

                MoneySpent[i]=0;
                Rates[i]=0;
                rem=1000;
            }
        }

        function updateFormElements(){
            for (i=0; i<20; i++){
                document.getElementById("r"+i).style.background='#bbb';
                document.getElementById("a"+i).value=Accounts[i];
                document.getElementById("m"+i).value=MoneySpent[i];
                document.getElementById("r"+i).value=Rates[i];
            }

            document.getElementById("budgettarget").value=budget;
            document.getElementById("remaining").value=rem;
            if(rem<0)
                document.getElementById("remaining").style.background='red';
        }

        function formInit(){
            initArrays();
            updateFormElements();
        }
```

my .js includes more functions and its included in the script part of the head but i need to pass this stage to check the rest, my HTLM code is the next:

```
<body onload="formInit();"><br />
    <form id="budForm" action="">
    <fieldset>
        <legend> Budget Calculator </legend>
        <table >
            <tr>
                <th colspan="6"> Red indicators over budget | Grey indicators read only zone! </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <th colspan="6"> Budget Target (&#8364;): <input id="budgettarget" type="text" class="boxmed"/>
                    Remaining (&#8364;): <input id="remaining" type="text" class="boxmed" readonly/>
                </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                <ul class="nodec">
                    <li><input id="a1" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a2" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a3" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a4" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a5" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a6" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a7" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a8" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a9" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a10" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                </ul>
                </td>
                <td>
                <ul class="nodec">
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m1" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m2" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m3" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m4" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m5" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m6" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m7" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m8" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m9" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m10" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                </ul>
                </td>
                <td>
                <ul class="nodec">
                    <li><input id="r1" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r2" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r3" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r4" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r5" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r6" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r7" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r8" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r9" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r10" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                </ul>
                </td>
                <td>
                <ul class="nodec">
                    <li><input id="a11" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a12" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a13" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a14" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a15" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a16" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a17" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a18" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a19" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                    <li><input id="a20" type="text" class="boxlg" value="AccountName"/></li>
                </ul>
                </td>
                <td>
                <ul class="nodec">
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m11" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m12" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m13" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m14" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m15" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m16" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m17" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m18" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m19" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                    <li>&#8364;<input id="m20" type="text" class="boxmed"/></li>
                </ul>
                </td>
                <td>
                <ul class="nodec">
                    <li><input id="r11" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r12" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r13" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r14" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r15" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r16" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r17" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r18" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r19" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                    <li><input id="r20" type="text" class="boxsm" readonly/>%</li>
                </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="just" colspan="4">
                    <button onclick="Calc(); BudFocus();">Calculate</button>
                    <button  onclick="formInit(); BudFocus)(;">Clear Form</button>
                    <button onclick='window.location.href="mailto:someone@gmail.com?Subject=Comments about budget calculator";'>Comments</button>
                    <button onclick="alert('blah blah blah');">About</button>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </fieldset>
    </form>
</body>
```

Comment: try following in you for loop document.getElementById("'"+"r"+i+"'")

Comment: no result...idk what else to try :/

Comment: @natan can you post your html as well? also, try placing js after html

Comment: posted it, i cant place it in the end because as you can see i want to call it with the onload attribute when the page starts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your loops start with `i = 0`, but in your html elements start with 1, for example `r1`. 
Of course, you may have some other errors (like already mentioned problem with `=` instead of `===`), but your code is not full, so it's hard to trace them.

Comment: oh yes!!!!!! i hate doing so stupid mistakes and take me so much time to find them...thanks a lot elena!!! appreciate really much :D

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is causing a problem:

`if (Accounts[i]=null)
                    Accounts[i]='Account #'+i;`

If you want to check whether `Accounts[i]` is `null`, use `==` (and often you'll want to use `===` in javascript). What you're doing right now is assigning `null` to `Accounts[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

You used =, you are supposed to use == or === when comparing .
= means your assigning null to account[i].